# Redirection problems

Tags: bash, shell

I've noticed something I don't understand while attempting to keep a progress log in a bash script. The issue can be reproduced using the following line:

```
var1=$(var2=$(echo "Hi!"))
```

After executing this line, `var2` remains empty. I don't understand what causes this behavior (if the output generated by `echo` is redirected somewhere, it doesn't go into `var1`), and more importantly, what I might do to avoid having this problem.

Any sort of help (explanation/pointers) would be much appreciated.

Comment: `var1` will be empty as well, since the assignment statement doesn't produce any output.

Comment: @chepner yes, but that doesn't interfere with what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why original string remains unchanged because of your use of:

```
 $(var2=$(echo "Hi!"))
```

Which basically changes value of `var2` in a sub shell and any changes made there remain in sub shell only. Once sub shell exits you don't get changed value in the parent shell.

Comment: Yes I had to update my answer accordingly otherwise it was looking as if I am answering a different question here :)